# Как в WordPress поменять Featured Image для поста

Tags: php, wordpress

Как в WordPress поменять Featured Image для всех постов на 1 изображение а посте?

Может, какой-нибудь плагин или код, который можно выполнить.

Answer (score 1):

В функции темы добавляем функцию:

```
function catch_first_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ Устанавливаем картинку по умолчанию если контент не имеет изображения
    $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

Далее в нужной части темплейта, где мы воводили Featured Image вызываем нашу функцию вместо существующей `<?=catch_first_image()?>`